# Python/Flask to get HTML inputs and store them in SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, flask

I am new to coding and trying to create an app that gets user inputs from HTML form and write them into a database. I am using Python/FLask and SQL Server.

Below is the part of code that is failing in the .py file:

```
@app.route("/users", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_users():
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json()
        new_user = {
            'email': request.form('email'),
            'start_date': request.form('start_date'),
            'end_date': request.form('end_date'),
            'ticket': request.form('ticket'),
            'login': request.form('login')
        }

        if not new_user['email']:
            response_object['status'] = 'failed'
            response_object['message'] = 'E-mail Address is required.'
            return jsonify(response_object)

        if not new_user['login']:
            response_object['status'] = 'failed'
            response_object['message'] = 'Agent ID is required.'
            return jsonify(response_object)

        if not new_user['start_date']:
            response_object['status'] = 'failed'
            response_object['message'] = 'Start Date is required.'
            return jsonify(response_object)
        
        if new_user['start_date'] == new_user['end_date']:
            response_object['status'] = 'failed'
            response_object['message'] = 'Start and End Dates cannot be the same.'
            return jsonify(response_object)
        

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=servername;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test.dbo.table')
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(email, start_date, end_date, ticket, login) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (email, start_date, end_date, ticket, login))
conn.commit()
response_object['message'] = 'The request has been submitted. Thank you!'
response_object['users'] = users
```

Here's what I get when I run the .py file:

> C:\oof>python login.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "login.py", line 74, in 
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(email, start_date, end_date, ticket, login) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (email, start_date, end_date, ticket, login))
> NameError: name 'email' is not defined

I am totally new to this and not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `%s` with `?` (question marks)? Have a read through [Binding Parameters](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Binding-Parameters) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing something that isn't defined.

Your sql params should either reference `new_user['email']` or `request.form('email')`.

Or you can create the missing email, start_date, ... properties and keep the sql parameters like it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your values as dictionary keys and not variables:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(email, start_date, end_date, ticket, login) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (new_user['email'], new_user['start_date'], new_user['end_date'], new_user['ticket'], new_user['login']))
```